# I am trying python threads ... but its giving me error saying : Exception in thread send

Tags: python-3.x

```
import threading

class Messanger(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            print(threading.currentThread.getName())

x = Messanger(name="send") 
y = Messanger(name="received")

x.start()

y.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change print(threading....) to print (self.getName())